# Php новый ключ ассоциативного массива

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить новую пару ключ-значение в ассоциативный массив вида:

```
Array ( [Title] => Название [Kod] => 3 [Gruppa] => 0 )
```

Строка

```
$arr['new_key'] =5;
```

Приводит к ошибке 
    **Notice**: Undefined index: new_key

Comment: Какая версия php? Не мучайте себя этим `array_merge`, это будет издевательство.

Все пишете правильно, это какая-то ошибка. Там точно присваивание?

Comment: Да, точно присваивание.

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.18

Comment: Что-то странное. Я в замешательстве, я бы винил эту сборку. Но при 5.3 я всегда гасил E_NOTICE. На всякий случай:

    error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE);

А лучше — переходите на 5.4, все, вроде бы, хорошо.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странная ошибка.

```
$arr = array('title' => 'Название', 'code' => 3, 'group' => 0);
$arr['new'] = 5;
```

Я всё верно понял?

Если да, то как вариант можно использовать array_merge(), но лучше всё-таки выяснить, в чем проблема.

Вариант с array_merge:

```
$arr = array_merge($arr, array('new' => 5));
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли, сделала через array_merge.